# ASP.NET MVC 5 prevent value changes

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

When I update my website, it hints me this problem "{"The conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.\r\nThe statement has been terminated."}"

The screenshot is list below, there is a value named RecordDate, it has value, but I will not change anything about that value so I didn't display it on the screen.

The problem is MVC automatically update that value for me, and the value of the date becomes 0000-00-01 i think, maybe something else, how to prevent it? just keep the origin value and update other columns.

[image: {"The conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.\r\nThe statement has been terminated."}]

The model class looks like this

```
 public class ShiftRecord
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
    [Display(Name="Company Vehicle?")]
    [UIHint("YesNo")]
    public bool IsCompanyVehicle { get; set; }
    [Display(Name="Own Vehicle?")]
    [UIHint("YesNo")]
    public bool IsOwnVehicle { get; set; }


    //Problem comes from this line
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString="{0:yyyy-MM-dd}")]
    public DateTime RedordDate { get; set; }
    [Display(Name="Day Type")]
    public Nullable<DayType> DayType { get; set; }
    [Display(Name="Normal Hrs")]
    public Nullable<int> NormalHours { get; set; }
    [Display(Name="Time and Half Hrs")]
    public Nullable<int> TimeAndHalfHours { get; set; }
    [Display(Name="Double Time Hrs")]
    public Nullable<int> DoubleTimeHours { get; set; }
    [Display(Name="Shift Hrs")]
    public Nullable<int> ShiftHours { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; } // System manager can leave any comment here

    public bool IsRead { get; set; } // has this shift record been read

    public virtual Employee Employee { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<JobRecord> JobRecords { get; set; }

}
```

In the controller, I didn't change anything about the model, so it looks like this:

```
      [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "ID,EmployeeID,IsCompanyVehicle,IsOwnVehicle,RecordDate,DayType,NormalHours,TimeAndHalfHours,DoubleTimeHours,ShiftHours,Comment,IsRead")] ShiftRecord shiftrecord)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(shiftrecord).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        ViewBag.EmployeeID = new SelectList(db.Employees, "ID", "LastName", shiftrecord.EmployeeID);
        return View(shiftrecord);
    }
```

And I didn't change Edit view as well, the only thing is I made RecordDate unchangeable, changed it from @Html.EditorFor to @Html.DisplayFor

```
<div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RedordDate, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.RedordDate)
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RedordDate)
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: You need to post your code, but I suspect you haven't included a hidden input so the model value is `DateTime.MinValue` when you post back and save.

Comment: `@DisplayFor()` does not render a control. When you post back, the model is initialized with the default value for `DateTime` which is `DateTime.MinValue`. One way to solve this is to add `@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.RedordDate)` although I would recommend using view models

Comment: I've changed @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.RedordDate) to @Html.HidenFor(model => model.RedordDate), but the problem is not solved, same problem.

Comment: BTW, I don't want to change the value, for example, the value for the column was "2015-1-1" before update, and after update, it should keep the same value "2015-1-1"

Comment: That's the purpose of the hidden input. You post back the original value unchanged. However you also exclude the value from posting back because its not included in your `[Bind(Include="..")]` list (possible typo - "RedordDate" vs "RecordDate"). Since you seem to be wanting to post back every other property, just remove the attribute (every thing is bound by default so its a bit pointless)

Comment: Solved! Thank a lot to point out the RedordDate, I don't know why I used that name, and forgive the non-native speaker.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is .net uses a default 1/1/0001 datetime min value, and the sql minimum value is 1/1/1753, which is incompatible.  If you use datetime?, it will resolve as null and work OK, or put in code to update the date to a default value before committing to the database.

Comment: I use DateTime, but I don't want to change the value. So the problem is MVC automatically update the value for me and I want to prevent it.

Comment: You can't because you are using DateTime, unless you write a model binder (http://aboutcode.net/2011/03/12/mvc-property-binder.html), or put a hidden field on the form so that a value posts back to the server that's not 1/1/0001.

Answer (score 0):

Your understanding is incorrect. ASP.NET MVC did not automatically update the value for you, the problem arises because you did not post `RedordDate` to the controller action so `RedordDate` will have its default value (i.e. `default(DateTime)`).

`DateTime` is a value type in .NET such that it cannot be `null` and its default value is `DateTime.MinValue` (i.e. `01/01/0001 00:00:00`).

You can solve it by making the `RedordDate` property `Nullable` by changing its type from `DateTime` to `DateTime?` so that it accepts `null` values.

One thing to note is that if you save this value back to a SQL Server but your underlying SQL datatype is `datetime` instead of `datetime2`, you will receive an exception since `01/01/0001 00:00:00` is out-of-range in `datetime`

Further reading:

1. MSDN recommends [using `datetime2` in a new development](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx)
2. [Difference between value types and reference types](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/parameters.html) explained by Jon Skeet

Answer (score 0):

You do render any controls for property `RedordDate` so when you post back, the `DefaultModelBinder` initializes a new instance of `ShiftRecord` and `RedordDate` has a value of `DateTime.MinValue` (1/1/0001).

Add a hidden control for the property to post it back

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.RedordDate)
```

Then in the POST method, remove the `[Bind]` attribute. Currently, even if the value is posted back, it will not bind because it has been excluded from the `Include` list. You have `RecordDate` but not `RedordDate` (a typo?). Note by default all properties will be bound so the attribute is not necessary unless you are specifically excluding properties.

A better alternative is to create a view model that contains only those properties you want to display and edit ([What is a view model in MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064316/what-is-viewmodel-in-mvc)) and then in the POST method, get the original data model and map the view model properties to it.

Side note: Can the vehicle be both `IsCompanyVehicle` and `IsOwnVehicle`?